# PigLatin translator giving out of bounds message when taking items from a vector

Tags: java, translators

```
package piglatinTranslation;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class PigLatin {

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {

        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int words = 1;
        Vector<Object> spacesList = new Vector<Object>();
        Vector<Object> translatedWordList = new Vector<Object>();

        String Phrase = Input.nextLine();
        Input.close();


        //Compares each character in the string 'Phrase'
        //If a character is found as an empty space, it adds to the word count and saves the index of the space in a vector
        for(int v = 0; v < Phrase.length(); v++)
        {
            char temp = Phrase.charAt(v);
            String tempString = Character.toString(temp);

            if(tempString.equals(" "))
            {
            words++;
            spacesList.add(v);
            }
        }


        //Takes each item in the vector (an integer for the index of each space within the sting)
        // and creates a substring for each word, putting it though the translation method
        // The translated word is added to a vector of strings
        for(int v = 0; v < words; v++)
        {
            if(v == 0)
            {
            int subStrEnd = (int) spacesList.get(v);
            Phrase.substring(1, subStrEnd);
            translatedWordList.add(Translate.translateWord(Phrase));
            }   
            else
            {
            int subStrStart = (int) spacesList.get(v - 1); 
            int subStrEnd = (int) spacesList.get(v);
            Phrase.substring(subStrStart, subStrEnd);
            translatedWordList.add(Translate.translateWord(Phrase));
            }
        }


        //Takes each string in the vector and combines them into one string to be returned to the user
        for(int v = 0; v < words; v++)
        {
        Phrase.concat((String) translatedWordList.get(v));
        }

        System.out.println(Phrase);

    }

}
```

A user should be able to input a string, and have it replied back to them translated through pig Latin.
For example:
Input: Hello
Output: Ellohay

Input: Hello, how are you
Output: ellohay, owhay areyay ouyay

I keep getting an out of bounds error at line 43.

That line should, in theory use the temporary variable 'v', and use that as a pointer to take the stored integer, the index of a space, to be used to separate the string into word substrings.

Comment: 1. Please clarify exactly at what line you're getting the exception. Also, if you could provide a scenario or input, that may make it easier to understand your code.

2. Consider formatting the code and post it again to make it easier to read.

Comment: I have edited the post and hopefully have done what you mean. If not i apologize for my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vector is being populated correctly, it's just that when there are n words there are only n - 1 spaces. So you would only want to loop up to words - 1. Generally in these types of situations though, you would just use spacesList.size() and you don't need to use the words variable at all.

Comment: I have added the full main program and what I am trying to do, sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I've updated my answer. Basically, the number of spaces is one less than the number of words, which is why you had an index out of bounds error.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that, thank you for the help though, and I'm sorry for the initial unclear post.